# Adding days to date in php is showing wrong dates

Tags: php, laravel, date

I am trying to add no of days to a given date in PHP
Here is my code

```
    {
        $invoiceDate = new DateTime($invoiceDate);
        $currentDateTime = new DateTime();

        $abs_diff = $invoiceDate->diff($currentDateTime)->format("%r%a");
        $loanTenor = $invoiceTenor - $abs_diff;

        $ca = date_add($invoiceDate, date_interval_create_from_date_string($loanTenor." days"));

        echo $abs_diff."<br />";
        echo $loanTenor."<br />";
        echo $ca->format('Y-m-d')."<br />";
}
```

Testing code

```
Route::get('test', function () {
    getLoanTenor('2021-07-04', 45);     // Output 2  43 2021-07-16
    getLoanTenor('2021-07-05', 45);     // Output 1  44 2021-07-18
    getLoanTenor(now(), 45);            // Output 0  45 2021-07-20
    getLoanTenor('2021-07-07', 45);     // Output 0  45 2021-07-21
    getLoanTenor('2021-07-08', 45);     // Output -1 46 2021-07-23
});
```

Output

the output date is not correct expect for **getLoanTenor(now(), 45);            // Output 0  45 2021-07-20**

Comment: All the output expect for getLoanTenor(now(), 45);  // Output 0  45 2021-07-20 @AnkitaDobariya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the object notation it's much easier to assign the `date_add` correctly

Plase change from

```
$ca = date_add($invoiceDate,date_interval_create_from_date_string($loanTenor." days"));
```

To

```
$add = DateInterval::createFromDateString($invoiceTenor.' day');
$ca = $invoiceDate->add($add);
```

This will output

> 2 : 43 => 2021-08-18
>
> 1 : 44 => 2021-08-19
>
> 0 : 45 => 2021-08-20
>
> -0 : 45 => 2021-08-21
>
> -1 : 46 => 2021-08-22